# React Native Android App Not Launching After Idle Period, Throws NullPointerException

Tags: react-native, nullpointerexception, expo

When the React Native Android application is idle for approximately 3-4 hours (even in an ideal state where I am capturing the device's GPS points data), and then an attempt is made to open the application, it does not launch for 1-2 seconds. After 3 seconds, if an attempt is made to open it again, the application launches with no issues.

During the 1-2 seconds when it does not launch, a crash report is sent to App Center, indicating the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void lc.b.c(android.content.Context, lc.b$b, java.lang.Runnable, pc.f)' on a null object referenceCrashVersion.

The stack traces of the NullPointerException is as below:

```
expo.modules.location.taskConsumers.LocationTaskConsumer.executeTaskWithLocationBundles expo.modules.location.taskConsumers.LocationTaskConsumer.didExecuteJob expo.modules.taskManager.TaskJobService.onStartJob android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob JobService.java:102 android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage JobServiceEngine.java:168 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:106 android.os.Looper.loopOnce Looper.java:205 android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:294 android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:8177 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:552 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:971
```

This issue occurs consistently across all versions of expo-location and expo-task-manager. I would like to seek clarification on whether this is an expected behavior in Android, causing a delay in launching the application, or if there is any assistance available to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.